# How to position tabs to the right side of tab bar?

Tags: tabs, position, css-position

I need to have some tabs at the left side of the bar as usual and 2 tabs locate at the **right end** of the bar.

My jsFiddle file is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chepukha/jXAZx/1/)

The **tab bar** must be located at some point in the **bottom** part of the screen. Hence, I have to position it as **absolute**. Consequently, I cannot locate the  tag **relatively** to the bar.

I've tried **float: right** but it didn't work either.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this get you going the right direction:

```
.tab-box {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;  /*I need to fix these tabs at some point at the bottom part of the screen*/
    bottom: 248px;
    left: 0;    
}
#complexTab {
    width:100%;
}
.tab-box a {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #3A3D42;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    background-color: #eee;        
     float:right;       
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 4px;    
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    margin: -2px;   /*remove space btw tabs*/
}

.tab-box a:first-child {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.tabcontent {
    height:248px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-top:1px solid #3A3D42;

    background-color:#757D8A;

    box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3) inset;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.hiden {
    display : none; 
}
```

Comment: I think I forgot to set width:100%. But, there is a small problem. When I make 2 tabs float to the right, the tabs on the left go up a bit. That makes a small gap btw these tabs and the content. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing things this way. If you want two separate tab menus, you should probably put them in separate containers.